# How to get the latest record inserted in dynamodb

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to retrieve the latest inserted record in dynamodb so that whenever a new record is inserted it the dynamodb table a lambda will trigger and fetch the record and pass it on to a python script.

I am writing the lambda in Python 2.7

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
  table = dynamodb.Table("html_contents")
  try:
     if (record.eventName == "INSERT") {
         #How to Retrieve the latest record 
     }
  except Exception, e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html).

Put your Lambda function as the event handler of a DynamoDB stream. It will then get triggered when anyone writes an item to a DynamoDB table.

Comment: I got that, I will have to create a trigger for Lambda to be executed, but how do i retrieve the latest record, if i don't have any keys?

Comment: Select the appropriate stream type (probably `KEYS_ONLY` or `NEW_IMAGE` ,depending on your use-case). Your Lambda will be then be executed every time an item in the table is modified *with* the keys/item itself. You don't need to retrieve it. See the example events here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-ddb-update You can filter on the event name to get inserts only.

Comment: Any way we can get last updated table item using "boto3 dynamodb"?